# In a new google sheet add-on continuously keeps loading

Tags: google-apps-script

When I create a new Google sheet and rename it something from 'Untitled spreadsheet', my add-on keeps loading.

[image]

I have to manually refresh the Google sheet to resolve this issue. I don't understand if this issue is somehow related to my code or is the default behaviour of the add-on.

Comment: If we can't reproduce your problem, we can't help you. What have you tried? What do the logs say? What does your `onOpen` trigger? We need a few more things to go on.

Answer (score 0):

#### It looks like what you are experiencing might in fact be a bug.

This has already been reported on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171728028); taking this into account, I suggest you to star the issue as all the updates regarding this will be posted there.

As you had already noticed, the way to go around this is to refresh the add-on manually.